# Link node output to plane/material

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes

Currently when I am editing a movie clip I'll export the output to a movie file and import it again in the next blender project.
For my current project (at university) I have to do that multiple times.
I wonder if there is a way to link the output directly to a plane (as material for example).

Couldn't find anything helpful in the net. I am pretty new in the blender universe.

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could enable the 'images as planes' addon and import the movie as an image plane.  The addon will handle movies in a wide range of formats.

Comment: Renders output to files, and textures reference files.  They can be the same files.  If you overwrite an image sequence being used for a material, it will get overwritten.  However, it won't be reloaded from disk until you reload the file or reload the image sequence.